# Confusing syntax with custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have found this code for a custom UITableViewCell :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    MyCustomCell *customCell = [[MyCustomCell alloc]init];

    MyCustomCell.cellImage = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for (UIView *view in views) 
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {                
            cell = (MyCustomCell *)view;

        }
    }
}
```

and I could not figure how this specific part works: `cell = (MyCustomCell *)view;`

I wanted to change it for my previously created instance of MyCustomCell (customCell)... How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes people will create a custom `UITableViewCell` using Interface Builder.  This person is just loading their custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and assigning it to the cell.  The line: `cell = (MyCustomCell *)view;` presumable works because `MyCustomCell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

This is just another technique for creating custom cells sometimes you'll see a similar thing done with tags.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's iterating over a collection of `UIView`s, or `UIView` subclasses. It's storing each iteration's variable into a pointer called `view`.

It's then simply casting the current `view` variable to a type of `MyCustomCell`. Presumably `MyCustomCell` extends `UIView`, so this is legal.

This is useful if you want to use methods specific to `MyCustomCell`, as Xcode won't know they exist, if you don't explicitly [Type Cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typecasting) your object.

Comment: And how could I cast it to a type o my instance of MyCustomCell instead?

Comment: @Lucase Pereira: I'm not sure I follow you. Right now it IS casting `cell` to `MyCustomCell`, if it is indeed an instance of `MyCustomCell`.